# What is the LEGO code for this part used as a camcorder?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone help me ID this part for my son? I think it comes from when I was a kid in the 80s-90s. I THINK that it had a VHS-type piece tacked to its side to be a camcorder, but don't quote me on that.

[image: Piece]

Answer (score 17):

That's [Minifigure, Utensil Camera with Side Sight (Space Gun)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4360). Part number is 4360.

[image]

As name suggest it was used both as a camera as well as a space gun.

[Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Black Tape Reels Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bp02#T=C) or "VHS" tape was commonly used with piece above in "camera" setup.

[image]

Comment: Odd that all the references I can find are the black one. No mention of a grey one.

Comment: @Modred189 check first URL. On the right side you'll see list of known colors for the part. You should be looking for "Light Gray".

Comment: @Modred189 Click on the check mark next to a post to accept it as the answer.